# Maven - Include external resource at the root of war file

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I have a resource file at the root of my maven project. The directory structure is as follows.

```
src/
pom.xml
resource_file
```

Inside pom.xml, I've mentioned the resource as:

```
<build>
   <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>.</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>resource_file</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Inside the war file, the `resource_file` is present at `WEB-INF/classes/resource_file`. I need the `resource_file` to be at the root of the war file. I can unzip the war file and move the `resource_file` to root and create the war file again. But, is there any way to accomplish this through maven itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is to put resources into `src/main/webapp` directory which will automatically put into the root of the resulting war file.

The [docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) has also an example of that.